# In what case runtime may generate a sorted method list in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

In the runtime source code (version of `objc4-723`), when sending message to an object, runtime can search method in two ways:

```
/***********************************************************************
* getMethodNoSuper_nolock
* fixme
* Locking: runtimeLock must be read- or write-locked by the caller
**********************************************************************/
static method_t *search_method_list(const method_list_t *mlist, SEL sel) {
    int methodListIsFixedUp = mlist->isFixedUp();
    int methodListHasExpectedSize = mlist->entsize() == sizeof(method_t);

    if (__builtin_expect(methodListIsFixedUp && methodListHasExpectedSize, 1)) {
        return findMethodInSortedMethodList(sel, mlist);
    } else {
        // Linear search of unsorted method list
        for (auto& meth : *mlist) {
            if (meth.name == sel) return &meth;
        }
    }

#if DEBUG
    // sanity-check negative results
    if (mlist->isFixedUp()) {
        for (auto& meth : *mlist) {
            if (meth.name == sel) {
                _objc_fatal("linear search worked when binary search did not");
            }
        }
    }
#endif

    return nil;
}
```

Runtime would judge if the method list is sorted and choose either linear search or binary search.

If the method list is sorted, obviously binary search is better, otherwise it should be linear search.

So my question is in what case the methods in one class would be sorted?

When would they be sorted? By who?

Answer (score 0):

Go have a look at when the `isFixedUp` flag is set to true.

https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-706/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm.auto.html

Basically, when a process is launched, dyld and the runtime both have "fix up" phases where they bind together symbols, optimize a bunch of stuff, and otherwise prep the app for operation.

ObjC's fixup phase can optimize the layout of the method lists to make subsequent lookups faster.  In particular, fixup will ensure that every selector is uniqued;  i.e. one object's `layoutSubviews` method's selector will be bitwise identical to another's and not just point to two copies of the same `char*`.  It also sorts the lists which, presumably, makes lookup faster, too.

Once fixed up, then method lookups can go down the fast path (call `findMethodInSortedMethodList`).   If not fixed up, then the runtime does a linear search (as that code demonstrates).

Comment: So what if I have category which has a list of method, when this method list is inserted into the base method list, would the whole method list be sorted at last?

Comment: Also, I see the `prepareMethodLists` is called at two places, one is when preparing the `base method list`, the other one is when preparing the `category method list`, but these two lists are sorted separately at different time, when they are combined together as one list, the sort function is not called, so can I say finally the whole method list is still not sorted?

Comment: I'm not sure.   I would expect that category based methods would be stored in optimized order, but I haven't looked at the implementation in quite a while.  It may be that the individual lists are optimally sorted and the search still grubs through each separately and the real speed comes from the dispatch cache?

Comment: what u just said, that's actually my real question. I am wondering if those two sorted list were combined into one list, and whether it is still considered as a sorted one or not?